# Only getting Dummy Output audio after resuming Kubuntu

Tags: drivers, sound, kubuntu, suspend, pulseaudio

After upgrading from Kubuntu 19.04 to Kubuntu 19.10 I've started having issues with only having a Dummy Output sometimes when resuming my PC from standby. I've noticed that this issue seems to occur somewhat randomly after some resumes but doesn't happen during others. Running `pulseaudio -k` always fixes the issue and it never occurs on a power-up or reboot.

Running `journalctl --since "1 day ago" | grep pulseaudio` after resuming my PC from standby gives the following output:

```
Nov 10 21:30:44 Linux-PC pulseaudio[3005]: W: [alsa-sink-ALC1150 Analog] alsa-util.c: Could not recover alsa device from SUSPENDED state, trying to restart PCM
Nov 10 21:30:44 Linux-PC pulseaudio[3005]: W: [alsa-source-ALC1150 Analog] alsa-util.c: Could not recover alsa device from SUSPENDED state, trying to restart PCM
Nov 10 21:30:44 Linux-PC pulseaudio[3005]: E: [alsa-source-ALC1150 Analog] alsa-source.c: Error opening PCM device front:0: No such file or directory
Nov 10 21:30:44 Linux-PC pulseaudio[3005]: E: [alsa-sink-ALC1150 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Error opening PCM device front:0: No such file or directory
```

I do have a modification in my `default.pa` config:

```
load-module module-echo-cancel source_name=noechosource sink_name=noechosink
set-default-source noechosource
set-default-sink noechosink
```

but I found the issue persisted even when the modification was disabled.

The controller that I use is the following:

`00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)`

and I am using kernel 5.3.0-18-generic.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE: After [discussing this issue with one of the pulseaudio devs](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/issues/766#note_323696) it was found that the nvidia proprietary driver I have installed was causing this. The issue would disappear when I  removed it and would come back when I reinstalled it.

Comment: Seeing the same issue on Ubuntu 19.10 (never seen before on 19.04) with nvidia HDMI sound as well as with the USB microphone in the B525 HD Webcam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying quite a few fixes, the solution that fixed the issue for me was running:

`sudo addgroup username audio`

where username is your username on your pc. After running this,  I haven't been able to crash pulseaudio in about 10+ suspend/resume cycles.