# ubuntu 22.04 audio output not working (dummy audio)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 22.04

I have just upgraded my ubuntu to 22.04 but the audio is not working.
In the setting, the audio option has only "Dummy Output" and the test fails.

I have tried to do what is reported  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403575/hdmi-audio-issue-ubuntu-22-04) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04)  but both do not work.

Thanks

Comment: I've fixed it: Visit https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407616/upgrade-from-21-04-to-22-04-audio-lost-dummy-output-only

Comment: just want to note that so far none of the solutions here have worked, and neither has upgrading to 22.10 (so don't waste your time trying that!!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrade from 21.04 to 22.04, audio lost (Dummy output only)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407616/upgrade-from-21-04-to-22-04-audio-lost-dummy-output-only)

Answer (score 39):

This looks very similar to [No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04)

that I could solve with:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

(credits go to https://askubuntu.com/a/1404159/139249)

Comment: This worked for me ( Ubuntu 22.04 LTS running on a ASUS Prime X570-PRO )

Comment: Worked on 22.04 with Nvidia HDMI audio.

Comment: Worked for me after audio was broken post-upgrade to 20.10

Comment: The first time it worked for me, but when sound disappeared second time it didn't.
Helped sudo alsa force-reload

Comment: Wonderful! Saving for my records. Thanks a lot. I tested this in a T430 with Ubuntu 22.04 which was upgraded from 20.04 and lost audio. Worked like a charm where other answers didn't help.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and it is working for me. Thanks

Comment: I am on 22.04 and it hasn't done anything for me

Comment: Worked for me .... Thank you ...

Answer (score 13):

**Pipewire restart for Ubuntu >= 22.10**

[Pipewire](https://pipewire.org/) became [the default sound framework since Ubuntu 22.10](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/05/ubuntu-22-10-makes-pipewire-default), so now you need to:

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire.service
systemctl --user restart pipewire-pulse.service
```

Learned from: [Is there another way to restart the sound system if pulseaudio/ALSA don't work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230888/is-there-another-way-to-restart-the-sound-system-if-pulseaudio-alsa-dont-work/1374982#1374982)

The audio framework may change, but [some things will never change](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXvBjCO19QY).

**For Ubuntu <= 22.04, try both `pulseaudio --kill` then `pulseaudio --start`**

The dummy audio is coming up for me after suspend, and to fix it I needed both:

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

Certain applications also needed to be restarted to pick up the new pulseaudio, e.g. VLC.

More details at: [No sound on wake, Dummy Output always takes over. 'pulseaudio -k' the fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191649/no-sound-on-wake-dummy-output-always-takes-over-pulseaudio-k-the-fix/1439226#1439226)

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.1, Lenovo ThinkPad P51.

Comment: this is mine output: E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process

Comment: Thanks this worked

Answer (score 1):

I have found this solution  [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html).

Firstly, I have kill pulseaudio:

`pulseaudio -k`

After that, I have check if my laptop uses snd_hda_intel:

```
lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
```

Luckily, it does.

I have, hence, run the following command:

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Finally, I have switched off and switched on my laptop. It seems that a simple reboot is not enough.

Best

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have edited my previous answer.

Comment: Recently, I have found that even what I have done is not enough. I have to reboot each log-in session in a recovery mode. this procedure seems to fix other issues that I am experiencing such as problems with python debug mode and video plays.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following to fix sound. This is not my fix but it worked because my hardware was Intel Pentium based. So if your hardware is Intel then edit this file:

sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Goto line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""

At the end Add to the following line enter the following:
snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0

Press CTL+X, type "y" for yes, press enter to exit

Then type the following:
sudo update-grub

Now reboot. You should have sound.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything else above, but then running

```
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

worked. I got immediately devices to show on: Settings->Sound->Output Devices instead of Dummy device.

I added the module name to /etc/modules to load it automatically on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the same issue after packages update on ubuntu 22.04, and was solved by updating preinstalled PipeWire to use ppa version.
You can follow the installation instructions here to see if it helps:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pipewire-on-ubuntu-linux

**UPDATE**:

After a few reboots, it stopped working again. New error showed me "org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1", so I dig deeper and found my `/run/user/1000` folder was owned by root (because of docker restart policy). I removed the folder and reboot the system.