# Ubuntu 22.04 Audio output not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

please i have exactly the problem here [ubuntu 22.04 audio output not working (dummy audio)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406646/ubuntu-22-04-audio-output-not-working-dummy-audio) and i also followed the solutions but nothing works. my computer audio doesn't still work. i am using the INFINIX Inbook X Corei5

Comment: Did your sound work on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure your output device is set to "LINE OUT".  However I too did notice some "new problem" with the latest kernel "5.15.0-35-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Sat May 21 02:24:07 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried many solutions
Finally I found a solution that works

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

I don't have much information about that unfortunately

Comment: My audio is suddenly not working. I tried this solution: sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio it says touch: cannot touch '/user/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio': No such file or directory