# No sound in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS after upgrading from 20.04 LTS

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, pipewire

I have no sound on my ThinkBook 14S-IWL Laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.1 anymore.

I have tried everything: Rebooting, regular shutdown, apt-update, updating GRUB, trying to install pipewire/wireplumber/pipewire-session-media and see if that works, no luck.

`$ aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`$ cat /proc/asound/modules`

```
0 snd_hda_intel
```

`$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30) (prog-if 80)
Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
Memory at c131c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at c1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
```

`$ systemctl --user status pipewire-session-manager.service`

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of pipewire-session-manager.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl --user daemon-reload' to reload units.
○ pipewire-session-manager.service
     Loaded: error (Reason: Unit pipewire-session-manager.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Aug 11 08:58:40 thinkbook systemd[2609]: pipewire-session-manager.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit pipewire-session-manager.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists
Aug 11 19:27:44 thinkbook systemd[2609]: pipewire-session-manager.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit pipewire-session-manager.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists
```

`$ systemctl --user daemon-reload`

Does seemingly nothing. The terminal doesn't complain but I also still do not have audio.

`$ pactl info | grep '^Server Name'`

```
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.48)
```

`$ aplay -l | grep HDMI`

Returns nothing.

Edit: After plugging my 3.5mm Headphones into the headphone jack and rebooting, I get sound over the headphones. But if I unplug the headphones, I get no sound.

[image: Image of Sound Output Devices in Settings]

[image: Image of Sound Output Devices in Volume Control]

Edit 2: Well now I do not have sound anymore. I have been updating & upgrading Ubuntu but still no fix.

Comment: Try booting with the previous kernel.

Comment: @ChanganAuto that did not work. Booting into 5.10.04-43 instead of 5.10.04-46 does not help.

Comment: I had the same problem with a Asus Zenbook UX463F since the 22.04 upgrade and this worked for me : https://www.linux.org/threads/solved-asus-zenbook-15-ux534f-realtek-hd-audio-problem.27384/post-94479

Answer (score 20):

I had the exact same issue, for which I found a solution from [No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04) :

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

(credits go to https://askubuntu.com/users/1156299/adam)

Comment: Also fix the issue when I upgrade from 22.0 to 22.10, thank you

Comment: Works on Xubunutu after updating from 22-04 LTS to 22.10.

Comment: Thank you my issue also  now thank you so much again :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error after upgrading. For me a *temporary* solution was to run

```
$ systemctl --user restart pipewire pipewire-pulse
```

after every boot.
Finally I found that `/usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d` was missing

```
$ ls -ld /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d
ls: cannot access '/usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d': No such file or directory
```

and

```
$ sudo apt --reinstall install pipewire-media-session
```

solved that for me. Some reports in the Internet say you might want to create this directory before running the reinstall (which IMHO might not be needed)

**Edit:**
Although audio worked for me after this, the error message

```
mod.rt: could not set nice-level to -11: Permission denied
```

remained and finally I also had to append

```
@audio   -  nice     -20
```

to `/etc/security/limits.conf` (as [seen here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/uklc0c/howto_troubleshoot_pipewire_crackling_pop_popping/)) to remove any error messages from the log. (reinstalling `rtkit` did not work for me either)

I checked the logs to be clean with:

```
journalctl -b 0 --user-unit=pipewire --user-unit=pipewire-pulse --user-unit=pipewire-media-session --user-unit=init.scope
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Neither the internal speakers nor the internal microphone were working and also external devices did not work.

---

**What worked for me**

I could make the speakers work by installing `firmware-sof-signed`:

```bash
sudo apt install firmware-sof-signed
```

And I could get the microphone working again by installing `alsa-ucm-conf` (from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2479854&p=14127685#post14127685, Post #7):

```bash
sudo apt install alsa-ucm-conf
```

I also tried a lot of other things (see below). Although I was always careful to revert changes I made when it turned out that they did not work, I'm not absolutely sure if the above is sufficient or whether it only works in combination with some other things I tried.

---

**System Information**

Lenovo Yoga Slim 7i 15 (15IMH05)

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Kernel: Linux 5.19.0-35-generic

Audio Codecs:

```bash
Codec: Nvidia GPU 94 HDMI/DP
Codec: Realtek ALC287
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
```

---

**Things I tried that made my speakers work but not the microphone**

- From [No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04/1424113#1424113) :

  Add `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and reboot
- From [Ubuntu 22.04 does not recognize my microphone's headset when plugging in, just audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413842/ubuntu-22-04-does-not-recognize-my-microphones-headset-when-plugging-in-just-a/1413873#1413873) :

  1. Get your audio codec with `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec`
  2. Go to https://kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html, look up the version of your codec and get the full name of it.
  3. Create/update the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file, and add the following line, replacing `<your_model>` with your own model from https://kernel.org: `options snd-hda-intel model=<your_model>`
  4. Reboot

---

**Things I tried that did not work for me**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74408508/ubuntu-22-04-no-sound-issue
- [Ubuntu 22.04 Sound Card Exists but is not Detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423435/ubuntu-22-04-sound-card-exists-but-is-not-detected)
- [ubuntu 22.04 audio output not working (dummy audio)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406646/ubuntu-22-04-audio-output-not-working-dummy-audio)
- [Ubuntu 22.04 Audio output not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407194/ubuntu-22-04-audio-output-not-working)
- [No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04)
- [HDMI Audio Issue Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403575/hdmi-audio-issue-ubuntu-22-04)
- [Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul/1259818#1259818)
- [Headset microphone not working on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04)
- [My microphone is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897437/my-microphone-is-not-working/)

Answer (score 0):

For me, only reinstalling `pipewire-media-session` solved the problem:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install pipewire-media-session
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to clean up headphones socket from dirty
It may think that that outside headphones connected

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1307638)

Comment: If any things don't work - try my solution. This is my situation, hope that helps