# No sound with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 22.04, alsa, chromebook

As shown in the picture, I have selected built-in audio, but there is no sound.

[sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkCYD.png)
[alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybUIK.png)

This is the result of `aplay -l`.

```
Card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  subdevice: 0/1
  subdevice #0: subdevice #0
Card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  subdevice: 1/1
  subdevice #0: subdevice #0
Card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  subdevice: 1/1
  subdevice #0: subdevice #0
Card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  subdevice: 1/1
  subdevice #0: subdevice #0
Card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  subdevice: 1/1
  subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I already tried this: [No sound in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS after upgrading from 20.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423121/no-sound-in-ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-after-upgrading-from-20-04-lts)

Comment: Does this solution work for you? https://askubuntu.com/a/1469281/124466

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the sound outputs were detected and listed (after pulseaudio manual restart) in `gnome-control-center`, but there was no sound in GNOME, it turned out that the `libcanberra` was misconfigured, the solution was to:

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-pulse
```

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1879989/comments/5

Answer (score 0):

Though gnome sound settings show that it's "Built-in Audio", it's not really the speaker but may be the output from your HDMI port (a monitor icon indicates that).

- Before checking other situations, you may:

  - try restart pulseaudio.service:

  ```
  systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
  ```

  - Does your laptop have headphone jack? try to connect it and check if your laptop can detect it.
- run `lsmod |grep snd` to check sound card module (aka driver) for your laptop. Whereas, if your laptop is upgraded from older version of kernel that with sound, you would need to reboot to older kernel. If it's working, then the sound issus may be kernel module bug. Inspect `dmesg` or `journalctl -k` for `snd` related errors and seek other guides to submit kernel driver bug.

Take a look to https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting , if simple reboot and your sound card is working, though there are some misconfigure on PulseAudio/ALSA.