# Ubuntu 22.04 - Bluetooth connects to headset but no sound

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have a Bluetooth 5.4 USB adapter, and I use Ubuntu 22.04 desktop. I have updated my Linux kernel to 6.4.12-060412-generic. I have tried `apt upgrade` as well.

I connect to the headset. It appears as paired, but no sound at all.

I have Pulseaudio, bluez, and everything people say in all tutorials, but I can´t seem to connect with sound to my Soundcore Q30.

By using `btmon`, sometimes I get a log of:

```
bluetoothd: src/profile.c:ext_connect() Hands-Free Voice gateway failed connect to E8:EE:CC:4E:77:80: Connection timed out (110)
```

By looking at `/var/log/syslog`, I could find some messages as well:

```
bluetoothd[8015]: src/profile.c:ext_connect() Hands-Free Voice gateway failed connect to E8:EE:CC:4E:77:80: Connection timed out (110)
```

By connecting it, I just see:

```
Aug 25 20:03:05 eduardo-jf systemd[2105]: Starting Bluetooth Manager...
Aug 25 20:03:05 eduardo-jf dbus-daemon[2133]: [session uid=1000 pid=2133] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Manager'
Aug 25 20:03:05 eduardo-jf systemd[2105]: Started Bluetooth Manager.
Aug 25 20:03:06 eduardo-jf ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[2425]: unable to update icon for blueman
```

But no sound at all.

And after some time, it disconnects with the following text:

```
bluetoothd[8015]: src/profile.c:ext_connect() Hands-Free Voice gateway failed connect to E8:EE:CC:4E:77:80: Function not implemented (38)

blueman-manager[8330]: blueman-manager 20.03.37 WARNING  ManagerDeviceMenu:141 fail      : fail g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError:  br-connection-canceled
```

Any ideas on what I could do?

Comment: What is the exact adapter and chipset you are using? You can use the [Debian "discover" package](https://wiki.debian.org/discover) to identify. Another option is to [use lspci on Linux to see your hardware](https://opensource.com/article/21/9/lspci-linux-hardware). Here is a [list of suggested USB and PCIe bluetooth hardware for Linux](https://medium.com/codex/bluetooth-5-on-linux-overview-of-kernel-supported-dongles-and-chipsets-c6f2b632b236), maybe that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423121/no-sound-in-ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-after-upgrading-from-20-04-lts) with a solution. Lots of people seems to have problems with Bluetooth and Ubuntu 22.04. Seems related to Pipewire...

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

It works for me (and others)

Comment: It didn´t work for me. The device is not even listed

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth && pulseaudio -k &&
pulseaudio --start

It works for me dev's!

Comment: I already have the module-bluetooth :(