# 22.04 audio routing not working

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

Audio routing does not work on my DELL Latitude 5400 laptop with a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.

I have tested with 2 different headsets that use bluetooth dongles. I have also tested connecting directly through bluetooth without the dongle. In both cases, I can select the headset in the sound settings, but sound output still gets routed through the built in speakers on the laptop.

I tried the fix suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407194/ubuntu-22-04-audio-output-not-working), but this had no effect.

Comment: Do the devices show up via `alsamixer` at all? I would also look at the troubleshooting steps listed [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#New_audio_source_streams_auto-select_to_%22blank%22_stream_instead_of_BT_headphones) for examples.

Comment: I haven't fiddled with alsamixer since the early 2000s, so not sure I'm handling this right, but no, I can't see them there. However, at the same time I CAN see them in Settings > Sound, and this also shows that the microphone is active.

Comment: Thank you for the link, @DankyNanky. Based on info there, I was able to resolve the issue. I use Slack and had this set to lauch at login. I disabled it and also included the code mentioned there (section Pulse overwrites ALSA settings) in my ~.profile file. After rebooting, things worked as they should.

Comment: feel free to answer your own quetion ;)