# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is producing strange noise instead of actual audio

Tags: 20.04, sound, 22.04, lenovo, headphones

I have recently updated to ubuntu 22 and though my headphone sound working fine, laptop speaker is not working. So I went through askubuntu page and followed this tutorial [ubuntu 22.04 audio output not working (dummy audio)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406646/ubuntu-22-04-audio-output-not-working-dummy-audio)

And now even my headphone sound is not working. It continues to produce weird radio sound. The sound continues even when I am restarting the OS. It only stops when laptop power went off. Do you guys have any idea? would help alot. Thank you!

Comment: @David: my apology, I have updated the question

Comment: This is likely a sink/source misconfiguration (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449690/pulse-audio-virtual-sinks-changing-on-alsa-underrun#450114 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311637/pulseaudio-setting-up-sinks-and-sources-for-a2dp-and-hfp-connections) but you'll have better luck if you report the problem to kernel bug tracker with a full report of your HW specs (which you didn't provide any)