# No sound from dummy audio output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

How do i fix this dummy Output issue? I'm having no sound on my machine:

[image: Screenshot of sound output setting]

I tried every method available on the internet but I see no progress at all.

My OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, OS TYPE: 64-bit. GNOME Version 42.9

Comment: Update your question to include Ubutu version (`lsb_release -a`), kernel version (`uname -a`) and hardware details (laptop model or motherboard/sound card details).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406646/ubuntu-22-04-audio-output-not-working-dummy-audio