No audio after update
I recently installed the new updates and after restarting I don't have audio anymore.
This is my alsa log
I followed sound troubleshooting from this page up to step 7, because it looks like it might not help if I try further and I might be better with a fresh install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure
Here are my Alsa Mixer Screenshot and pavucontrol screenshots.



I fresh installed the next version of ubuntu and it still didn't work. Then I went back to ubuntu 20.04 and it worked until I did an update (even though I installed a backup/restore app called Timeshift.)
The only way I got audio after that is by following this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1462678/103512
I hope it helps someone
